# Jackson Deserialize Polymorphic Classes not as Array

Tags: java, json, jackson, polymorphism, deserialization

I'm trying to do a simple example of deserializing json into polymorphic classes. The deserialization fails with the error:

```
org.codehaus.jackson.map.JsonMappingException: Could not resolve type id 'aField' into a subtype of [simple type, class ...SubClassA]
```

If I try the deserialization for a single subclass, just using the JSON for that class, it succeeds, but when I put the two classes together inside the SubClassTestObject, it fails. Any ideas for fixing this? Do I need to write a custom deserializer?

Here is my JSON:

```
{
    "classA":{
        "aField":"A",
        "baseField":"baseA"
    },
    "classB":{
        "baseField":"baseB",
        "bField":"B"
    }
}
```

Here are my classes:

```
@JsonTypeInfo(use=JsonTypeInfo.Id.NAME, include=JsonTypeInfo.As.WRAPPER_OBJECT)
@JsonSubTypes({
    @JsonSubTypes.Type(value = SubClassA.class, name = "classA"),
    @JsonSubTypes.Type(value = SubClassB.class, name = "classB")
})

@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
public abstract class AbstractSimpleClass {
    String baseField;

    public String getBaseField() {
        return baseField;
    }

    public void setBaseField(String baseField) {
        this.baseField = baseField;
    }
}

public class SubClassA extends AbstractSimpleClass {
    String aField;

    public String getaField() {
        return aField;
    }

    public void setaField(String aField) {
        this.aField = aField;
    }
}

public class SubClassB extends AbstractSimpleClass {
    String bField;

    public String getbField() {
        return bField;
    }

    public void setbField(String bField) {
        this.bField = bField;
    }

}
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
public class SubClassTestObject {
    @JsonProperty("classA")
    SubClassA a;

    @JsonProperty("classB")
    SubClassB b;

    public SubClassA getA() {
        return a;
    }
    public void setA(SubClassA a) {
        this.a = a;
    }
    public SubClassB getB() {
        return b;
    }
    public void setB(SubClassB b) {
        this.b = b;
    }
}
```

And here is my test:

```
@Test
public void testBoth() throws IOException, URISyntaxException {
    ClassLoader classLoader = getClass().getClassLoader();
    json = new String(Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get(classLoader.getResource("test/so-example.json").toURI())));
    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
    mapper.registerSubtypes(SubClassA.class, SubClassB.class);

    SubClassTestObject testObj = mapper.readValue(json, SubClassTestObject.class); //Fails here
    SubClassA a = testObj.getA();
    SubClassB b = testObj.getB();

    assertTrue(a.getBaseField().equals("baseA"));
    assertTrue(b.getBaseField().equals("baseB"));
    assertTrue(a.getaField().equals("A"));
    assertTrue(b.getbField().equals("B"));

}
```

Comment: Updating question...

Comment: In the future, please review your question before you post it. This is a very different scenario.

Comment: My bad, after seeing the first answer I saw what one of the problems was so I fixed it, and it turned into another issue.

Comment: Do you want to use types info in your `SubClassTestObject `? or is it happends to be that you just have such classes and you know exactly what type to expect in your SubClassTestObject { SubClassA a; SubClassB b;} because you can put     `@JsonTypeInfo(use=JsonTypeInfo.Id.NONE)` above `SubClassA` and `SubClassB` and this code will work for you

Comment: you can change only     `public class SubClassTestObject {
        @JsonProperty("classA")
        @JsonTypeInfo(use=JsonTypeInfo.Id.NONE)
        SubClassA a;

        @JsonProperty("classB")
        @JsonTypeInfo(use=JsonTypeInfo.Id.NONE)
        SubClassB b;}` and the rest code you provided will work, but then you don't need type info at all

Comment: I still get the same error complaining about aField. What is the function of the JsonTypeInfo.Id.NONE?

Comment: @PunDefeated here is demo: https://gist.github.com/varren/032b79976269cf66278f32411a5d1b7c it 100% works for me. `JsonTypeInfo.Id.NONE` will suppress `@JsonTypeInfo(use=JsonTypeInfo.Id.NAME, include=JsonTypeInfo.As.WRAPPER_OBJECT)` from `AbstractSimpleClass` because you dont need it, you already know in your `SubClassTestObject` what type of objects you want, so you can remove `@JsonTypeInfo(use=JsonTypeInfo.Id.NAME, include=JsonTypeInfo.As.WRAPPER_OBJECT)` from `AbstractSimpleClass` or add supressing annotations with  `JsonTypeInfo.Id.NONE`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After your edit:

This

```
@JsonProperty("classA")
SubClassA a;
```

is completely unrelated to

```
@JsonTypeInfo(use=JsonTypeInfo.Id.NAME, include=JsonTypeInfo.As.WRAPPER_OBJECT)
```

The `JsonTypeInfo.As.WRAPPER_OBJECT` is meant to be implicit. It's not something you map in your POJOs. You won't be able to map your current JSON with this strategy. Either do what's below or change your `JsonTypeInfo` to use a `JsonTypeInfo.As.PROPERTY` for example, then provide the corresponding `@type` (and its appropriate value) property in the JSON.

---

Pre-edit:

Your `SubClassTestObject` class has two properties, `a` and `b`, because of

```
public SubClassA getA() {
    return a;
}
public SubClassB getB() {
    return b;
}
```

These aren't present in your JSON. And since you told Jackson to ignore unknown properties, it doesn't fail to deserialize. However, both of them are going to be left uninitialized.

The JSON you meant to deserialize is

```
{
    "a": {
        "classA": {
            "aField": "A",
            "baseField": "baseA"
        }
    },
    "b": {
        "classB": {
            "baseField": "baseB",
            "bField": "B"
        }
    }
}
```

which has `a` and `b` for your root `SubClassTestObject` object. And those use wrapper objects with the appropriate `JsonTypeInfo` name.

Comment: Hmm okay, I have to keep the json the same, though. I'm updating my question.

Comment: Is this achievable without changing the JSON? I'm doing this simple case for practice, but in my project I'll have to deal with JSON in the format that it's currently in. It looks like my only option then may be to write a custom deserializer for the SubClassTestObject.

Comment: @PunDefeated With your current JSON, no, I don't see clear cut way with `JsonTypeInfo`.

Comment: Alright, thanks. I'm accepting your answer as it specifies that this is not possible, which is certainly an answer.